# 英語版WindowsのPowerShellで日本語ショートカットを作成するには

Tags: windows, powershell

Windows10/PowerShell5.1環境を考えています(より古い環境にも対応していると嬉しいですが)。

PowerShellでショートカットを作成する方法を検索すると、[こちら](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-6#creating-a-desktop-shortcut-with-wscriptshell)に書かれているような、 `WScript.Shell` を利用した例が多くヒットします。
この方法は、日本語版Windowsではうまく動作したのですが、英語版Windows(Windows Server 2016 on EC2)で同様のコマンドを実行するとエラーが発生しショートカットは作成されませんでした。

script(UTF-8 with BOM):

```
$file= $Env:Temp + "\ほげほげ.txt"
$shortcut = $Env:Temp + "\ほげほげショートカット.lnk"

$WsShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut($shortcut)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $file
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $file
$Shortcut.Save()
```

結果:

```
> .\create.ps1
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\create.ps1:6 char:1
+ $Shortcut.TargetPath = $file
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Unable to save shortcut "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\???????????.lnk".
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\create.ps1:8 char:1
+ $Shortcut.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

検索したところ、同様の質問をされている方がいらっしゃった

- [Create shortcut with Unicode character - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542005/4506703)

のですが、

- リンク先はC#であり、PowerShellで同様の方法を実現するにはどうすればいいか分からない
- [Windows8(以降？)では動作しないというコメント](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542005/create-shortcut-with-unicode-character#comment62622437_13542488)もあり、結局どうするのが正しいのか不明瞭

のような理由で解決には至っておりません。

---

(以下、回答を頂いた後追記)

[sayuriさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/48262/2808)を元に、次のようなスクリプトを書いて実行してみたところ、英語環境でも想定通り日本語名ショートカットを作成することができました。

`create_shortcut_revised.ps1`(UTF-8 with BOM):

```
$srcDir = Join-Path $Env:TEMP "src"
$srcName = "ほげほげ.txt"
$srcPath = Join-Path $srcDir $srcName

$destDir = Join-Path $Env:TEMP "dest"
$destName = "ほげほげショートカット.lnk"
$destPath = Join-Path $destDir $destName

## 前準備
# New-Item $srcDir -ItemType Directory -Force
# New-Item $destDir -ItemType Directory -Force
# New-item $srcPath -ItemType File -Force

New-Item $destPath -ItemType File -Force

$shl = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$dir = $shl.NameSpace($destDir)
$itm = $dir.Items().Item($destName)
$lnk = $itm.GetLink

$lnk.Path = $srcPath
$lnk.Save($destPath)
```

現状、まだこの処理が何を行っているのかちゃんと理解できていませんが、メンバ名から逆算するに、`New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application`で得られているのが [`Shell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell)オブジェクトなのかなと思いますので、この辺りを見ていこうかと考えています。

また、情報後出しになってしまって申し訳ありませんが、今回解決したい問題は[他の人が作成した不特定の人が使うプログラム](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/pull/2577#issuecomment-419929983)内のものなので、採れる対応にはいくらかの縛りがありました。

Comment: ここ[Windows Script Programming - 2017年9月](http://scripting.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2017/09/index.html)の記事で原因が考察されているようです。いろいろと複雑な条件があるならば、PowerShell/WSHだけで処理せず、ショートカット作成するためだけの外部コマンドを作ってみては？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

本件に限らずコントロールパネルの Language for non-Unicode programs の項目を Japanese (Japan) に設定することをお勧めします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

現象から察するに`WScript.Shell`を利用したコードにはどこかに非Unicodeを扱っており、その個所で日本語文字が文字化けしていると思われます。上記設定を行うことで非Unicode文字を日本語と扱うことができ、日本語版Windowsと同様の結果を得ることができるようになります。

例えば、zipファイルに含まれている非ASCII文字ファイル名の解釈方法などもこの設定を参照しています。

---

以下は、前述のコントロールパネルの設定に依らない解決策です。具体的には[Create shortcut with Unicode characterの回答コード](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542488/4315484)をPowerShellに移植した例です。

```
$destPath = $env:TEMP
$shortcutName = "ほげほげショートカット.lnk"

# Create empty .lnk file
$path = Join-Path $destPath $shortcutName
New-Item $path
# Create a ShellLinkObject that references the .lnk file
$shl = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$dir = $shl.NameSpace($destPath)
$itm = $dir.Items().Item($shortcutName)
$lnk = itm.GetLink
// Set the .lnk file properties
$lnk.Path = ...
$lnk.Description = ...
$lnk.Arguments = ...
$lnk.WorkingDirectory = ...
$lnk.Save($path)
```

見ての通り、PowerShellのコマンドレットとしては`Join-Path`、`New-Item`、`New-Object`くらいしか使いませんので、ほとんどバージョンに依存しません。ComObjectの`Shell.Application`もPowerShellや.NET Frameworkより歴史がありそうなくらいなのでたぶん大丈夫です。

---

> Windows8(以降？)では動作しないというコメント

いくつか要因があるようで、PowerShellには影響しないものも含まれていました。上記コードが動かないようでしたら、エラーメッセージを添えてコメントください。